# JAVA JPA : join two entities on attributes with annotation

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, annotations

I am working on a project that is not mine and I need your help.
Currently I have two table on database :

```
TABLE A :  id | prop | prop ... | id_link
           1  |                 | 2
           2  |                 | 1
           3  |                 | 2
           4  |                 | 3


TABLE B :  id | prop | prop ... | id_link
           1  |                 | 1
           2  |                 | 1
           3  |                 | 1
           4  |                 | 2
           5  |                 | 2
           6  |                 | 2
           7  |                 | 3
           8  |                 | 3
           8  |                 | 3
```

In Java, I got this :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "A")
@Getter
@Setter
public class A{
    
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    some properties...

    @Column(name = "id_link")
    private Long idLink;
```

and

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "B")
@Getter
@Setter
public class B{
    
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    some properties...

    @Column(name = "id_link")
    private Long idLink;
```

And I want something like this when I retrieve an instance of A :

```
"A": [
                {
                  "id": 1,
                  ...
                  "B": [
                    {
                      "id": 4,
                       ...
                    },
                    {
                      "id": 5,
                       ...
                    },
                    {
                      "id": 6,
                       ...
                    },
                  ]
                },
]
```

But I've been stuck for 2 days, I'm trying with OneToMany annotations or this kind of annotations, but without success. Please help me ! :)

Comment: `I'm trying with OneToMany annotations or this kind of annotations` post what you tried?

Comment: Based on the json, you need `OneToMany`

Answer (score 0):

Based on your json you class A should have `OneToMany` relation with class B. Something like this

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "A")
@Getter
@Setter
public class A{
    
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "a")
    private List<B> bList;
```

and B class will be

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "B")
@Getter
@Setter
public class B{
    
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;
    
    @ManyToOne
    private A aObject;
```